# Flutter CupertinoPicker UI breaks and children are not displayed properly

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, cupertino-widgets

I am quite new to Flutter and was trying to implement the CupertinoPicker Widget.
When I press a button I want to be able to replace the current CupertinoPicker with another one.
Unfortunately when I try this the text from the second UI is quite distorted.

Here are some images to help you understand my issue.
[image: First Screen]
[image: Faulty Screen]

What exactly am I missing here?

Here is my code

[Code on Github](https://github.com/Xango/CupertinoPicker.git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the `Center` widget with a `Container` widget. Here's a screenshot of the app and the code.

[image]

```
Widget _second() {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: CupertinoPicker(
          selectionOverlay: null,
          onSelectedItemChanged: (value) {},
          itemExtent: 30,
          children: [
            Text("City 1"),
            Text("City 2"),
            Text("City 3"),
            Text("City 4"),
            Text("City 5"),
            Text("City 6"),
            Text("City 7"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```